# Angular - Initialization and get value from DOM

Tags: angular, dom

In my app, I have a cart component listing all the items. A link from a product gets me to that component.

`cart.component.html`

```html
<tbody class="table-body">
                    <tr *ngFor="let item of productsList">
                        <td>{{item['name']}}</td>
                        <td><input class="input is-primary" style="width: 30%;" type="number" value="{{item['qty']}}" id="quantity">
                            <button class="button is-small is-success is-light" style="margin-left: 20px;" (click)="updateQuantity(item['id'], item['price'], getValue())">Update</button>
                        </td>
                        <td>{{item['price']}} $</td>
                    </tr>
           </tbody>
```

`cart.component.ts`

```js
constructor(private configService: ConfigService, private url: ActivatedRoute) { 
  this.url.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    this.catId = params['catId'];
    this.productId = params['productId'];
    this.productPrice = params['productPrice'];
  });
}

  ngOnInit() {
    let item = {"id":this.productId, "price": this.productPrice, "qty": 1};
    this.configService.getCard(item).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        this.productsList = response;
        this.total = this.productsList.pop();
      }
    );
  }

  updateQuantity(productId, productPrice, productQuantity){
    let item = {"id":productId, "price": productPrice, "qty": productQuantity};
    this.configService.getCard(item).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        this.productsList = response;
        this.total = this.productsList.pop();
        console.log(this.productsList);
      }
    );
  }

  getValue(){
    let updateButton = document.getElementById("quantity");
    console.log(parseInt(updateButton.value));
    return parseInt(updateButton.value);
  }
```

In the initialization, I put the quantity to one. But when the user update the quantity, the new value is supposed to be considered.

[image]

But for whatever reasons, even when I update the quantity, it still remains 1. It seems that my `getElementById().value` returns 1 instead of the value of the input. Is it because I go through `ngOnInit()` again ?

Comment: In your template you have a for-loop in which you set an `id`, so you basically have n elements with the same id, what contradicts the idea of an `id`.
Regarding the value: using angular you shouldnt access dom-elements directly. Additionally you should use `formGroups` and `formControls` and bind those to your inputs. With your current approach you really dont need angular.

Comment: I see, then I will use the forms. Thanks !

Comment: EDIT : I use ng model for 2 ways databinding and it worked. Thanks !